# Google Apps email forwarding to regular Gmail account

Tags: gmail, google-apps-email, email-forwarding

I have a Google Apps email account that I'd like to close. But, I'd like to retain emails that go to the account.

Can I forward emails that are aimed at my Google Apps account to my regular Gmail account? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

You can [set up forwarding the regular way](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/10957?hl=en), but of course that will no longer work if you close your Google Apps account.

Once you close your account, any messages sent to it will be lost. If you have access to the DNS records for the domain, you can set it up to use a cheap/free email service, and forward messages from that service to your Gmail account.

Comment: Thanks for the message Vidar. That makes sense. What free email service would you recommend?

Comment: I won't recommend any specific service. But googling for [free email with custom domain](https://www.google.no/search?q=free+email+with+custom+domain) will be a good starting point.

Comment: Does it matter that I won't continue to pay for my web hosting services?

Comment: You shouldn't have to pay for hosting, that is a separate service. But you need to pay for domain registration, of course.

Comment: So, if I stop paying for my web hosting (done by a different group), I will still be able to receive emails? I want to make sure I understood you. Thanks.

Comment: You should read the contract you're cancelling carefully. You can cancel the _web hosting_ part just fine (you're not hosting a website), but you need to keep the domain, and you need a mail service connected to that domain.